# C# N way merge for external sort

Tags: c#, merge, sorting

Whats the best way to implement an N way merge for N sorted files?

Lets say I have 9 sorted files with 10 records each? How do I merge these files to create a big file with 90 sorted records?

Comment: With or without duplicate records?

Comment: What prevents you from doing an in-memory sort and writing to a file? In other words, what are your constraints?

Comment: I'd be tempted to say, load or simply append all 9 files and re-sort. Given the overhead of file access I can't think of any good reason to try to interlace the data files while you are merging. If you are dealing with a total record load larger than available memory then live is more complex.

Comment: With or without dups.

In memory is not possible because the file is 2 GB and over.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that there could be a lot more data then you gave in your example. If you can open all the files simultaneously you can use this algorithm:

- Read the first line from each file, so you have 10 lines in memory, one from each file.
- Put the lines into a priority queue by sort order.
- Take the least element (sorted first) out of the priority queue and write to the output file.
- Read one more line from the corresponding file the line came from and put that into the priority queue.
- Repeat until all files are read to the end.

Note that you don't have to read all the files into memory at once, so this will work well if you have a reasonable number of large files, but not if you have a lot of small files.

If you have a lot of small files, you should merge them in groups to make a single output file for each group, then repeat the process to merge these new groups.

In C# you can use for example a `SortedDictionary` to implement the priority queue.

Comment: If you are reading one line at a time, wouldn't there be significant disk overhead switching back and forth between file sectors?  It would seem reading in a buffer of data for each file would be an important factor

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response

This is the algorithm I was planning to use.

So here is the next question

I have a list that contains the temp filenames in my example 9 filenames.

But this number can be different each time depending on the data in the original file and the memory specified by the user.

How can I have a varying number of open streams depending on the number of sorted files I created from the original file?

Comment: @user262102: Make a List<Stream>. Add streams to the list. Use foreach loop to iterate over the list of streams. Don't forget to close all the streams when you're done with them.

Comment: @tbischel: modern disk controllers have big caches and a lot of intelligence in them. I wouldn't worry about it unless real-world testing showed it was a problem.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that helped.

What would be the best way to track what file the lowest record came from to start the process?

Comment: @iser262102: the suggestion of using a sorted dictionary as a priority queue is a good one. You could use the dictionary as a map from records to the stream that produced the record.  I'll draw a sketch of it.

Comment: Hey Eric,
         I finally did it...:) I really appreciate your help. Performance is not that great but works well for my purpose. 71 seconds for 185 MB file.

Basically, I am a QA and was writing a generic compares tool. The compares are blazing fast but they run of out of memory and hence this additional step for bigger files.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Addressing the comments in the other answer:

If you have an variable number of files, here's what I'd do. This is just a sketch to get the idea across; this code doesn't compile, I've gotten the method names wrong, and so on.

```
// initialize the data structures
var priorityQueue = new SortedDictionary<Record, Stream>();
var streams = new List<Stream>();
var outStream = null; 
try
{
  // open the streams.
  outStream = OpenOutputStream();
  foreach(var filename in filenames)
    streams.Add(GetFileStream(filename));
  // initialize the priority queue
  foreach(var stream in streams)
  {
    var record = ReadRecord(stream);
    if (record != null)
      priorityQueue.Add(record, stream);
  // the main loop
  while(!priorityQueue.IsEmpty)
  {
     var record = priorityQueue.Smallest;
     var smallestStream = priorityQueue[record];
     WriteRecord(record, outStream);
     priorityQueue.Remove(record);
     var newRecord = ReadRecord(smallestStream);
     if (newRecord != null)
       priorityQueue.Add(newRecord, smallestStream);
  }
}
finally { clean up the streams }
```

Does that make sense?  You just keep on grabbing the smallest thing out of the priority queue and replacing it with the next record in that stream, if there is one. Eventually the queue will be empty and you'll be done.

Comment: One problem is my record is a string array and I can't use that as a key for the dictionary.

I need to do it that way, because I parse the csv file to preserve value in each field and depending on the columns provided by the user as keys, I figure out the smallest record using quicksort.

Hope it is clear, so I am unable to use th algorithm above.

Any other ideas?

Comment: @user262102: Create a comparer object that implements that logic and pass it as the ordering function to the sorted dictionary.

Comment: This is a very simple algorithm to implement but do note that using _SortedDictionary_ means if you have duplicate data in your input, it will throw an exception. So either use a _IPriorityQueue_ or if you don't want duplicates then check for existence before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy might depend on amount of data.

1. If data will fit in memory you can read all data into a list, sort it, and write it out
2. If you want to remove duplicates use a HashSet instead of a list
3. If it will not fit in memory, open all files for reading, compare the first record of each file, and write out the lowest. Then advance the file which you read. Loop over all files until they are all exhausted and written to the new file.
4. If you want to remove duplicates, do like above, but skip any record equal to the last written.

Here's a code example which reads in N sorted text files and merges them. I have not included duplicate checking, but it should be easy to implement.

First a helper class.

```
class MergeFile : IEnumerator<string>
{
    private readonly StreamReader _reader;

    public MergeFile(string file)
    {
        _reader = File.OpenText(file);
        Current = _reader.ReadLine();
    }

    public string Current { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _reader.Close();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Current = _reader.ReadLine();
        return Current != null;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get { return Current; }
    }
}
```

And then code to read and merge (it should be refactored for clarity in production):

```
// Get the file names and instantiate our helper class
List<IEnumerator<string>> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\files", "*.txt").Select(file => new MergeFile(file)).Cast<IEnumerator<string>>().ToList();
List<string> result = new List<string>();
IEnumerator<string> next = null;
while (true)
{
    bool done = true;
    // loop over the helpers
    foreach (var mergeFile in files)
    {
        done = false;
        if (next == null || string.Compare(mergeFile.Current, next.Current) < 1)
        {
            next = mergeFile;
        }
    }
    if (done) break;
    result.Add(next.Current);
    if (!next.MoveNext())
    {
        // file is exhausted, dispose and remove from list
        next.Dispose();
        files.Remove(next);
        next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't use priority queue, don't use IEnumerable. Both are very slow.

Here is a fast way to sort or merge sorted files in external memory:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/fast_external_sort.aspx

Comment: Hi Guys,
        Thanks for the replies, I did implement it using the merge sort algorithm. It is pleanty fast for my QA purposes. It compares 2 files (about 300 MBs each) with about 30 million cells each in close to 2 minutes. This includes the time for the merge sort as well as the subsequent compares.

Thanks,
Bhavin